# Улучшение раздела справки «Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Улучшение раздела справки «[Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)».

---

Мы верим, что сообщество само ответственно за модерацию содержимого сайта, поэтому, помимо того, что любой участник получает дополнительные [привилегии](/help/privileges) по мере получения репутации, на каждом сайте (кроме новых сайтов находящихся в «бете», где сотрудники Компании назначают [*временных* модераторов](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)) существует демократическая процедура выборов в модераторы. Выборы проводятся регулярно, чтобы определить, тех участников, которые, по мнению сообщества, смогут поддерживать порядок на сайте. Модераторы выбираются на неопределённый срок, но при желании они могут сняться с этой должности (или, в крайне редких случаях, их просят покинуть пост).

Мы ожидаем от модераторов следующих качеств:

- терпение и честность;
- умение увлечь своим примером;
- уважение к товарищам по сообществу в словах и делах;
- умение выполнять ненавязчивую, но решительную модерацию сайта;
- быть лидером сообщества и решать редкие (как хочется надеяться) споры и исключения.

Кроме того, все модераторы должны соблюдать [соглашение о модерации](/legal/moderator-agreement).

#### Модераторы – это участники, решающие острые вопросы сообщества, отсрочивание решение которых может привести к нарушению жизни сообщества.

Основной задачей модератора является отслеживание сообщений, отмеченных сигналом тревоги. Под каждым сообщением имеется небольшая ссылка с флажком тревоги, которую может использовать любой участник с репутацией 15 баллов и более. Сообщения могут быть отмечены тревогой за спам, агрессию или в случаях, когда требует внимание модератора, с комментарием или ссылкой, объясняющих суть проблемы. Как только кто-либо из участников установит сигнал тревоги, у всех модераторов в шапке сайта увеличится на единицу счетчик сигналов тревог.

Если вы видите, что в системе появилось что-либо выходящее за рамки правил сообщества или по какой-то причине требующее внимание модератора, [не стесняйтесь отмечать такое сообщение сигналом тревоги](/help/site-moderators)! Основная задача модераторов отреагировать на такое сообщение и принять необходимые меры.

Модераторы имеют дополнительные инструменты, позволяющие устранять эти редкие чрезвычайные ситуации.

- Голоса модераторов – решающие. При любом голосовании - за закрытие, открытие, удаление, восстановление, агрессию, перенос и пр. - голос модератора сразу превышает предел, необходимый для принятия решения, и решение вступает в силу сразу после того, как только модератор отдает свой голос.
- Модераторы могут блокировать сообщения. За заблокированные сообщения нельзя голосовать и их нельзя изменять никаким способом.
- Модераторы могут устанавливать [защиту на вопросы](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/). Защищенные вопросы допускают ответы только от пользователей с репутацией более 10 баллов.
- Модераторам доступно больше системной информации, включая статистику по голосованию (но не имена голосовавших за сообщение) и учётные записи пользователей.
- Модераторы могут [временно приостанавливать доступ](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) к учетным записям участников и удалять их при необходимости.
- Модераторы могут выполнять различные работы по обслуживанию сайта, такие как объединение вопросов и меток, утверждение синонимов меток и пр.

Модераторы выполняют множество рутинной работы: удаление очевидного спама, закрытие явно нетематических вопросов и удаление части сообщений с наихудшим рейтингом. Идеальный модератор делает очень немногое, но все, что он делает, приносит значительную пользу, заметную сообществу и является очень целенаправленным.

Если у вас есть вопросы о причинах тех или иных действий модератора, задайте их на Мете. Будьте **конструктивны и вежливы**; модераторы стремятся действовать во благо сообщества, но иногда они, как и все мы, допускают ошибки или вынуждены идти на компромисс, что может понравиться не всем участникам.

Подробнее о нашей философии модерации можно прочитать в [«Теории модерации»](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

#### Модераторы выступают в роли связующих между сообществом и компанией Stack Overflow

Модераторы сообщества могут поднимать вопросы, связанные с процессом модерации, обращаться к сотрудникам компании Stack Overflow за советами, а также за административной и технической поддержкой.

Кроме того, модераторы могут привлечь дополнительное внимание к программным ошибкам, запросам новых функций и другим вопросам, которые влияют на работу сайта, если сообщество не может решить эти вопросы самостоятельно на Мете.

Внешне модераторы сообщества отличаются от других участников символом ромба (♦) рядом с их именами. Часть сотрудников Stack Overflow также обозначена ромбом рядом с их именем. Обычно это разработчики или администраторы сообщества, либо другие сотрудники, которые взаимодействуют напрямую с участниками и решают вопросы, связанные с программными ошибками на сайте или занимаются иными проблемами сообщества. Сотрудники Stack Overflow в своих учетных записях указывают свою принадлежность к компании.

Узнайте, кто является [модераторами этого сообщества](/users?tab=moderators), или просмотрите список [модераторов на всех сообществ сети Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators).

Comment: Очень сложные предложения в первом абзаце, даже длиннее чем в прошлой версии.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Каким критериям должен соответствовать участник сообщества для избрания в модераторы?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1404)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вопрос общий. Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь вносить правки!

Comment: я на учёбе, одним глазом подглядываю в Ru.SO )